# neovim integration in vs code errors

Tags: neovim

I get these 2 errors the moment I open vscode. Neovim works from the terminal but I don't think it does in vscode. I have no idea why because I am a novice and I just started seriously getting into programming like 2 months ago so please bare with me, this is my first post. Thank you in advance!

MainController: Neovim spawn error: spawn /.../.../.config/nvim EACCES

MainController: Neovim was disconnected

Answer (score 0):

try change the path to the executable programm, not the bin folder.
It fixed mine issue

Answer (score 0):

If you using Windows, remove all NeoVim installed. Re-install with Chocolatey.

```bash
choco install neovim
```